# How to write Group by in Inner Join

Tags: sql, group-by

Here I Have Two tables:

**Orders**

```
OrderId     OrderName
1            Apple
2            Mango
```

**Cust**

```
Id     Name        OrderId       Price
1      John           1           50
2      John           1           100
3      Mic            1           10
4      Mic            2           10
```

Sql Join Query:

```
SELECT Orders.CustName,Items.IteamName,Orders.Price
FROM Orders JOIN Items ON Items.Id = Orders.Id
```

Group By

```
SELECT Orders.CustName, SUM(Price) FROM Orders GROUP BY Orders.CustName
```

How can I Write `Group by` in Join?

Comment: Same strategy as before.

Comment: Your sample tables are called `Orders` and `Cust`.  Your sample code has `Items`.  Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
Select Orders.CustName, Items.IteamName, SUM(Orders.Price)
FROM
Orders JOIN Items ON Items.Id=Orders.Id
GROUP BY 
Orders.CustName, Items.IteamName
```

The fields that you doesn't aggregate you put at the `GROUP BY`clause.